# Ubuntu Docker Container change timezone

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

How can I able to change my docker container timezone?

This is my Host timezone (Correct Timezone)

[image]

This is my Docker Container timezone(Will change Timezone)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be OS (Container OS) dependent. Some common ways are
`ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago /etc/localtime`, or `export TZ=America/Chicago` or editing /etc/timezone

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Already fixed "or editing /etc/timezone" :)

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed** 
**sudo nano /etc/timezone** then change it your prefered timezone

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to set environment variable `TZ=<your timezone>` somewhere. This could be for example in the [docker run command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables), [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) or in [docker-compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment).